# Voltage and Current Sensor for Alternating Current

Tags: arduino, microcontroller, current-measurement, voltage-measurement

I want to measure the voltage and current of a AC powered device using a micro controller like Arduino. I am unable to find it.(I am new to these).
Is there a circuit or sensor which isolates from the AC and able to measure voltage and current with voltage and current values accurately.
I have a supply of 240V and the device consumes around 10A

Comment: Consider looking for sensors for volts, amps and phase angle.

Comment: There are range of current sensor from Allegro. You will be able to buy it as a module.

Comment: Have a look at the [Open Energy Monitor](http://openenergymonitor.org) project where all of this has been solved already.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, are you sure you need to measure voltage? If you have fixed voltage supply then measuring voltage is only necessary if you need high precision data, otherwise you can assume that your supply keeps it constant.

Second, this is AC, so do you know exactly what you want - amplitude? RMS? both?

In any case, take a look at [ZMPT101B](https://www.aliexpress.com/item/33057948871.html) module, they are all over the web. And [here](https://surtrtech.com/2019/01/21/easy-measure-of-ac-voltage-using-arduino-and-zmpt101b/) is a good article on using this module with Arduino. It also explains the importance of calibration and good algorithm to obtain RMS value. Fortunately, Arduino libraries for that are also available.

Now, for current I'd suggest using so called "[non-invasive current sensor](https://www.robotshop.com/ca/en/seeedstudio-non-invasive-ac-current-sensor-15a-max.html)". It is safe to use by clamping it around one of the power wires and then reading 0..1V output with Arduino ADC. There are cheaper solutions (you can check the selection on same Robotshop site) that require soldering and therefore extra safety measures.

I strongly recommend finding good insulated enclosure which you can use to hide both voltage and current sensor and have only low voltage connections for Arduino coming out. The enclosure would have a cord with plug for your power supply and a socket for plugging the device. If you have 3rd (earth ground) wire in your supply make sure it is properly connected to the output socket. Keep good separation between AC and logic wires.

Once again, safety first. Do not plug your sensor module into power source until enclosure is properly closed.

UPDATE:

Just came across this module: [PZEM004T](https://www.aliexpress.com/item/32994493910.html). It is all over the web with tons of videos, instuctables and Arduino libraries. It is also often sold with nice plastic enclosure. With a bit of precaution it can be used relatively safely as a good power meter. Some people add wireless modules to it, so that no physical connection between monitoring device and sensor is necessary.

Comment: *"First, are you sure you need to measure voltage? "* If he wants e.g. to calculate the power he needs to momentarily voltage and current.

Comment: @Oldfart Even if OP wants to calculate power my statement about precision remains valid. For a _known_ load a simple estimate can be made by using constant values for both voltage RMS and power factor. That leaves only current to be measured, which can be done without ever coming into contact with dangerous voltages.

Comment: Thanks for the replies.
My need for this is to calculate the power consumption of individual servers. So, need power monitoring for individual outlets.